# KnockoutJS not displaying select

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

I'm trying to get a select menu to display options from a list created in an external script sheet.  The list:

```
window.list = [
        {
            Name: 'Male',
            Value: 1,
            notApplicable: 'me'
        },
        {
            Name: 'Female',
            Value: 2,
            notApplicable: 'me'
        },
        {
            Name: 'Not Specified',
            Value: 3,
            notApplicable: 'me'
        }
        ];
```

The HTML:

```
<li>
  <label for="5">Sex</label>
  <select name="" id="5" data-bind="options: list, optionsText: 'Name', optionsValue: 'Value', optionsCaption: 'Choose',  value: user.SELECT"></select>
</li>
```

When displayed in the browser, the drop down menu displays no caption and no drop down options.  This is for a registration page where the user will select their sex.

Comment: This should be in a view model object, not the Window. Example in @pax162 answer shows this as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you getting errors in the console? If your view model does not have a user.SELECT property, the binding will fail. I added a user.SELECT property and it seems to work: http://jsfiddle.net/BEEuQ/1/

html:

```
<select name="" id="5" data-bind="options: list, optionsText: 'Name', 
    optionsValue: 'Value', optionsCaption: 'Choose', 
    value: user.SELECT"></select>
```

js:

```
var vm = {
    list : [ { Name: 'Male', Value: 1, notApplicable: 'me' }, { Name: 'Female', Value: 2, notApplicable: 'me' }, { Name: 'Not Specified', Value: 3, notApplicable: 'me' } ],
    user:{
        SELECT:ko.observable()
    }
}

ko.applyBindings(vm)
```

Also, you might want not want to put you data directly on the window object. Globals are bad in Javascript. Create a namespace (object) and put everything there.